# How to do conditional sum with PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
ID  Quantity     date
100    20     1-NOV-15
100    30     1-OCT-15
100    10     1-OCT-15
100    5      1-AUG-15
101    4      1-AUG-15
```

I want to sum for each `ID` all the `Quantity` till the `Date` associated with the `ID` meaning I want to get this:

```
ID  Quantity     Date      sum
100    20     1-NOV-15      65       // sum all ID 100 till 1-NOV-15
100    30     1-OCT-15      45       // sum all ID 100 till 1-OCT-15
100    10     1-OCT-15      45       // sum all ID 100 till 1-OCT-15
100    5      1-AUG-15       5       // sum all ID 100 till 1-AUG-15
101    4      1-AUG-15       4       // sum all ID 101 till 1-AUG-15
```

I'm having trouble getting this result. This is what I wrote:

```
Select ID,Date,SUM(Quantity)
From a
Group by ID,Date
order by ID
```

I can't find out how to tell the `SUM` to pass on all records which are the same `ID` and their `Date` is smaller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a cumulative or running sum.

```
Select ID, Date, SUM(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE)
From a;
```

EDIT:

The default framing option is `range between unbounded preceding and current row` as opposed to `rows between unbounded preceding and current row`.  If you used the latter, the results would be more like:

```
ID  Quantity     Date      sum
100    20     1-NOV-15      65       // sum all ID 100 till 1-NOV-15
100    30     1-OCT-15      45       // sum all ID 100 till 1-OCT-15
100    10     1-OCT-15      15       // sum all ID 100 till 1-OCT-15
100    5      1-AUG-15       5       // sum all ID 100 till 1-AUG-15
101    4      1-AUG-15       4       // sum all ID 101 till 1-AUG-15
```

However, the default is appropriate for this problem.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS), the default framing option *is* `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. After testing both of your queries, they do return the same (and correct) result.

Comment: Marth is correct both queries return the same result.  Can you please explain how it works? I read the link you gave but I don't understand in the first solution how it knows till where to count? what will you have to change if the desired solution was indeed what he sowed with the 15 and 45 results.

Comment: @John : It's a bit hard explaining the concept of window functions, especially in a comment, but the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-window.html) does a good job I think (although it doesn't say anything about the `RANGE` clause, but after reading it the first link should be much clearer). As for your second question, it's a bit hard to say really : how do you distinguish between the two `1-OCT-15` rows ? I.e why would the results be 15 -> 45 (ie (5+10) -> (5+10+30)) and not 35 -> 45 ?